# Elastic Load Balancer on local development PC

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I'm starting working on a new project where an Elastic Load Balancer, in front of two tomcats, will be used. At least that's the candidate solution. In this project there will be a development environment hosted on each developer's pc. Each developer needs to have an exact replica of the final production topology. For EC2 instances, this is going to be achieved with oracles virtual box (ubuntu VMs).

The problem/question is: how is possible to replicate an ELB in a local environment in order to have the same behaviour. I suppose it is risky to use HAProxy or mod_proxy of Apache for load balancing in local environments because the preceding software products have different behaviour than ELB (for example in the way they transfer HTTP headers).

So the final questions are:
Is there a suggested workaround? 
Does anyone by experience have any proposals/workarounds for such cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Good question. Here's how I would do it:

1. Create an ELB and an EC2 instance specifically for development testing, and add the instance to the ELB.
2. Create a listener on the ELB for each developer's workstation (i.e. http/3001 --> http/3001, http/3002 --> http/3002, and so forth). Note that you can only create one healthcheck on an ELB -- to get around this you can install apache or nginx on the test instance and just have the ELB check 80/tcp to ensure the instance is always in service).
3. From each developer's workstation, establish an ssh tunnel to the test instance (i.e. `ssh -fN -i ~/.ssh/ec2_keypair.pem ec2-user@ec2-instance-fqdn -R 3001:localhost:3001`).

Under this configuration, each developer's local environment is available at `http://elb-fqdn:developer_port`. You will probably want to lock down the security group that's assigned to the test ELB so that only connections from certain IPs are allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Its kind of complicated :) I will try to test it and see if this an acceptable solution. Well, it must be since there is no other candiadate. +1 from me.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit complicated, but outside of having the developers deploy their code directly to a development environment on EC2 instances before testing, it's the only way to accomplish what you're asking. Thanks for the upvote. :)